# wildcard to variable to comma-joined string

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using a makefile to control a software pipeline. I need to pass as a parameter a comma-separated list of directories, aka

```
--dirs output/a,output/b,output/c
```

Which are unknown. I want to do something like:

```
dirs = output/*
dirString = ",".join(dirs)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually better to do these things in *make* I find. Noddy parsing makes handling of `,` and  more tricky than it ought to be though :-(

```
space :=
space += # $space is a space
comma := ,
comma-separate = $(subst ${space},${comma},$(strip $1))

list := a b  other     stuff  # trailing space
$(error [$(call comma-separate,${list})])
```

The recipe in the accepted answer would obviously be `command $(call comma-separate,$+)`

Comment: I don't think this will work: `$(call ...)` is executed on the literal argument `$+`, which is expanded in a later processing phase.

Comment: @reinierpost No it's fine if used in the recipe as per your post below. The entire recipe is held by _make_ as a single recursively expanded variable. It is expanded by _make_ just as _make_ has decided it needs to run said recipe. At this point all the target macros (`$@`, `$*` et. al.) are valid and expand as expected.

Comment: Indeed it works, sorry about that. This is explained [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles) but I didn't understand it well enough.

Answer (score 1):

A shell is used to execute the commands, so you can invoke any utility available to construct your command line. For instance, on a Unix-like system:

```
output/result: output/*
    echo $+ | sed 's/ /,/g' | xargs command > $@
```